# Highcharts markers positioning errors in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, highcharts

Ive been working with some code implementing highcharts into a page with images for markers. When not using custom marker images the markers display in the right position in all browsers, however when using custom markers for the data the images are pushed to the bottom right corner of the graph in IE8.

[Here is a sample of the code which is causing this.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2450739/work/index_bare.html) I've noticed that setting the inverted property to true makes the graph work correctly, however the graph needs to be display with the x and y axis inverted.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like known bug, reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1343

Comment: Rats, I was fearing that. Ive also discovered that not using images also works fine. the combination of images and inverted axis settings seem to be what breaks it.

Comment: Bugreport is asking for feedback